# I want check if exist file with Angular2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to check if a file exists with JTest in Angular, but I am aware that I only check for a string, I don't check if the file actually exists :

```
it('I check files i18n', () => {
    const i18nEs = '../../../server/i18n/es.json';
    const i18nIng = '../../../server/i18n/en.json';

    expect(i18nEs).toBe('../../../server/i18n/es.json');
    expect(i18nIng).toBe('../../../server/i18n/en.json');
  });
```

I've tried the documentation, but either the document doesn't contain that kind of documentation, or I didn't look at the right one.

Comment: Checking if a translation file exists should not be part of a unittest

Comment: But I can check If the file exist and I can learn for next check...